# How do I implement a nested callback pattern properly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to build a scraper using Node.js where I need some help implementing the callback pattern properly.

I'm having trouble implementing it the right what. What I am looking to do is something like this

```
var client = function(){};

client.prototype.init = function() {
  // do something
}

client.prototype.A = function(callback) {
  // do something
  // run callback

  if(recursive_condition_fulfilled)
    myclient.A(callback)
}


var myClient = new client();

var myCallback = function(callback){
  // do something
}

myClient.init();
myClient.A(myCallback);
```

The problem arises when I have an async function B() which runs inside A()

```
client.prototype.A = function(callback) {
  // do something

  this.B();

  // wait for B
  // once B is done
  // run callback()

  // then run the following
  if(recursive_condition_fulfilled)
    myclient.A(callback)
}


client.prototype.B = function(callback) {
  // do something
  // run callback
}
```

#### How do I implement the later part when B is resolved? (where it says)

```
// wait for B  
// once B is done  
// run callback()
```

Comment: Make `B` accept a callback or return a promise. B has to explictly tell you when it's done.

Comment: @FelixKling so similarly if I have C inside B, should I also do that to C? Is there a better approach for this problem?

Comment: Promises are a good solution for dealing with nested asynchronous operations. But yes, every function that is async would have to return a promise. Check out https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird which implements promises for anode.

Comment: do all instances of client call myclient.A ?

Comment: @webduvet no, my bad they should be doing this.A()

Comment: @FelixKling so I should be creating another function that wraps `....  // run callback()

  // then run the following
  if(recursive_condition_fulfilled)
    myclient.A(callback)  .....` and then send it as a callback to B ?

Comment: If you want to solve it with callbacks, yes.

Comment: BTW you B calls this.A and  A calls this.B...